# how to put multiple variables in if condition?

Tags: javascript

I want to make script which
if I press button with unchecked checkboxes (email and sms)
then show #hidedbox

now it works only on Email checkbox
so if you uncheked email then press button it will show #hidedbox
but how can i change this script to work if "email" and "sms" **both** are not checked then show
#hidedbox ??

Thanks :)

```js
function myFunction10() {
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("ADemail_");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("ADsms_");
  var hidediv = document.getElementById("hidedbox");
  if (btn1.checked == true) {
    hidediv.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    hidediv.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function myFunction11() {
  var btn4 = document.getElementById("hidedbox");
  if (btn4.style.display === "block") {
    btn4.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  background-color: grey;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hidedbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 55px 20px;
  opacity: .9;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#okaybtn {
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label for="coupon_question"><input type="checkbox" name="ADemail_" id="ADemail_" value="ADemail_" class="input-cbox"> Email</label>
<br/><br/>
<label class="pl-30"><input type="checkbox" name="ADsms_" id="ADsms_" value="ADsms_" class="input-cbox"> SMS</label>
<br/><br/>
<a id="coupon_question" onclick="myFunction10()"><span>Press this button</span></a>

<div id="hidedbox">
  <span>check any box.</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="okaybtn" onclick="myFunction11()">okay I will do.</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a condition i.e it will only work if the `email` button is not checked and `SMS` button is not checked.

Since `btn1.checked` is a `boolean` value you don't need to do as `btn.checked === true`

It would be predictable if you would use `===` in place of `==`.

> === (Triple equals) is a strict equality comparison operator in JavaScript, which returns false for the values which are not of a similar type. This operator performs type casting for equality. If we compare 2 with "2" using ===, then it will return a false value.

```js
function myFunction10() {
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("ADemail_");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("ADsms_");
  var hidediv = document.getElementById("hidedbox");

  if (!btn1.checked && !btn2.checked) {
    hidediv.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    hidediv.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction11() {
  var btn4 = document.getElementById("hidedbox");
  if (btn4.style.display === "block") {
    btn4.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  background-color: grey;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hidedbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 55px 20px;
  opacity: .9;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#okaybtn {
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label for="coupon_question"><input type="checkbox" name="ADemail_" id="ADemail_" value="ADemail_" class="input-cbox"> Email</label>
<br /><br />

<label class="pl-30"><input type="checkbox" name="ADsms_" id="ADsms_" value="ADsms_" class="input-cbox"> SMS</label>
<br /><br />

<a id="coupon_question" onclick="myFunction10()"><span>Press this button</span></a>

<div id="hidedbox">
  <span>check any box.</span>
  <br />
  <span id="okaybtn" onclick="myFunction11()">okay I will do.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! @SAM ! Thank a lot for your helping with "===" information! this is exatly what i want!! thanks again and have a great day!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Just make a small change in the **myFunction10**

```
function myFunction10() {
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("ADemail_");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("ADsms_");
  var hidediv = document.getElementById("hidedbox");
  if (btn1.checked == true || btn2.checked == true){ //Made changes here
    hidediv.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    hidediv.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! @Root ! thanks for your help!! :D by your help, i can understand how to use || properly! :) thanks and have a great day! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if *either* `btn1.checked` or `btn2.checked` are equal to true. To do this, you can use the `||` (or) operator.

By the way, checking if `btn1.checked == true` is redundant because the `== true` bit is unnecessary. It can be replaced with just `btn1.checked`.

```js
function myFunction10() {
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("ADemail_");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("ADsms_");
  var hidediv = document.getElementById("hidedbox");
  if (
    btn1.checked == true ||
    btn2.checked == true
  ) {
    hidediv.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    hidediv.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function myFunction11() {
  var btn4 = document.getElementById("hidedbox");
  if (btn4.style.display === "block") {
    btn4.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
a {
  background-color: grey;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hidedbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 55px 20px;
  opacity: .9;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

#okaybtn {
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label for="coupon_question"><input type="checkbox" name="ADemail_" id="ADemail_" value="ADemail_" class="input-cbox"> Email</label>
<br/><br/>
<label class="pl-30"><input type="checkbox" name="ADsms_" id="ADsms_" value="ADsms_" class="input-cbox"> SMS</label>
<br/><br/>
<a id="coupon_question" onclick="myFunction10()"><span>Press this button</span></a>

<div id="hidedbox">
  <span>check any box.</span>
  <br/>
  <span id="okaybtn" onclick="myFunction11()">okay I will do.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Jacob Lockwood ! thanks for your help to let me know about what is necessary or not. thanks and have great day ! :D